# Specialty screws for reinforcing wooden shelf supported by pins

Tags: screws, shelving, hardware

This is a 6 foot tall MDF + Veneer shelf unit. Adjustable shelves with pin holes. Most are supported as shown.

The shelf I am remounting uses screws in the pinhole and the dovetailed inserts in the shelf slip down over the screws. This is the one that confers more stability to the unit. You can see the end of one of these in the bottom hole in the first picture.

I have only two of the screws, and need four. Can't find them anywhere. Any suggestions? I suspect the conformation of the head is important for fit.

Usual mount hardware

[image: Usual mounting hardware]

[image: Screw in hold from opposite shelf]

Screw in shelf from opposite shelf (above)

[image: Screw in relation to insert before installation]

[image: insert]

Comment: Take the screw to hardware/big box/automotive stores until you find one with a screw thread gauge and a pair of calipers. Carefully measure the threads to find the correct pitch, the thread diameter, and the head diameter. Then you can expand your search online. Unfortunately, though, this is nothing but shopping advice and any place that someone might find the screw today could quit carrying them and/or be out of business tomorrow, hence shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: Usually at this point I'm piloting and countersinking for standard screws. Is that an option here? Can you hide the heads?

Comment: The key is to have the head sticking out of the hole so the shelf would sit down over the head like it would a regular pin or dowel. So countersinking would defeat the purpose. Also these screws are much more secure in the side so this specific shelf is very secure and near permanent to provide stability to the double wide shelf piece. Thanks, though.

Comment: take your sample to a place that specialises in fasteners, they will be able to measure it and heopefully find a suitable part, or at-least tell you what you have.